# the short spin in the wind

Tags: phrase-meaning

> If they think that they will maintain to the end the equanimity of
>   their prayer-lives, they are wrong, because the law demands the full
>   traitor's penalty, **the short spin in the wind** and the conscious
>   public disembowelling, a brazier alight for human entrails. It is the
>   most horrible of all deaths, pain and rage and humiliation swallowed
>   to the dregs, the fear so great that the strongest rebel is unmanned
>   before the executioner with his knife can do the job; before each one
>   dies he watches his fellows and, cut down from the rope, he crawls
>   like an animal round and round on the bloody boards.
>
> — Wolf Hall by Hilary Mantel

Is it a part of the punishment? With a hint from the last sentence ("cut down from the rope"), I am guessing it is to do with some kind of hanging.

Comment: Since you asked. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanged,_drawn_and_quartered

Comment: I've got it. It's a short time of struggle while the traitor is hanged. Thank you. You could have written an answer with all these info.

Answer (score 1):

In general, they're talking about the hanging and disembowelment of a traitor. A short spin in the wind can either mean that while the traitor is hanging, the movement of the fall is making their body spin in the wind:

> Spin: To rotate rapidly; whirl.

Or the "short spin" might be taken out-of-context from:

> Spin: rapid descent of an aircraft in a steep spiral.

To mean the traitor will have a short, rapid descent in the wind while he falls to his death.

Comment: The traitor is hanged but not to the point of death. He's let down when he's almost dead, so he can suffer the rest of the punishment. Hence "short spin".